# Keep valid HTML markup for "render()" for dynamic value as attribute

Tags: reactjs

I am reading React and not happy to keep the valid HTML markup for render() function. Following is code snippet.

Working Code:

```
import React from "react";
export  default class Header extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const title="I am title";
    return (
      <img title={title} src="./test.png"></img>
    )
  }
}
```

Not working Code when used valid HTML markup (title value with double quote):

```
import React from "react";
export  default class Header extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const title="I am title";
    return (
      <img title="{title}" src="./test.png"></img>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to keep valid HTML markup to keep my development easy and easy to trace if any HTML markup issue.

Is there any way to use the dynamic attribute value with double quote?

Comment: Are you talking about how the code coloration in your code editor ? If so, there is syntax plugin for JSX in most editors

Comment: No, I want to use double quote so that I can  use valid HTML markup. HTML markup without double quote in attribute value is not a valid markup.

Comment: I want React to read {var_name} even when it is inside double quotes.

Comment: This is only JSX, which will get translated to valid HTML markup. React will do the job for you and hopefully `title={title}` will get translated as `title="content_of_var_here"`. :)

Comment: I understand this is JSX, but I want to use HTML markup as my normal way. Most of the editor when I type attribute with "=" sign then it automatically add empty double quotes. Therefore I simply added "{title}" which didn't work. I was thinking if there is any way to do it.

Comment: There is not. `<img title="{title}"/>` will get translated to `React.createElement('img', {title: "{title}"})`, where title is being interpreted as a string.

Comment: ok, thanks. May be I should write webpack plugin to do this translation.

Comment: Would be a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to care about that. JSX is compiled to JS syntax which render HTML for you. We can consider it as a second abstraction layer over HTML.

Moreover, there are a lot of differences between HTML and React's components implementation.

Closing textarea HTML:

```
<textarea />
```

Closing textarea JS:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

The same about setting attributes, you wont be able to have it valid.

But the most important that, you should understand that it is an abstraction layer. That is why some people are propagating against JSX, because a lot of peopleand confused. So they promote using plain JS using [hypescript](http://html-to-hyperscript.paqmind.com/)(see right part).

[Here](https://medium.com/@jador/jsx-4b978fbeb290#.s03aun1ft) is a nice article about that.

Comment: I am not convinced to add layer on HTML. My preference is use the normal HTML inside JSX. I do see few webpack plugin for "className" and "htmlFor", I think I can write separate plugin for "{var_name}".

Comment: I think you are just going wrong direction, adding one more layer without having any advantages and adding more pain and confusion. But I partially understand you :)